# Typescript: Defining an Object

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to define an object:

```
errors = {}
```

Then I want to set some items like:

```
errors['a'] = 'aaaa';
errors['b'] = 'bbbb';
errors['c'] = 'cccc';
```

But I get errors saying that property 'a' (or any of the other) are undefined. For solving that I add those items to the initial value:

```
errors = {
'a': '',
'b': '',
'c': ''
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the type I have to assign to errors?
2. How can I define an object with dynamic properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the type I have to assign to errors?

```
let errors: { a: string, b: string, c: string }
```

> How can I define an object with dynamic properties?

```
let errors: Record<string, string>
```